# MCU to MCU I2C communication

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, serial-bus

I have 2 MCUs and I want to connect them together over an I2C bus. MCU1 will be the controller while MCU2 will be the target. Only these 2 MCUs are on the bus. This configuration is fixed and I cannot change it.

There are 2 scenarios. In the first scenario only MCU1 and MCU2 are on the bus, while in a second scenario there are some additional I2C devices also connected on this shared bus.

My main purpose to connect them as above is to send data from MCU2 (target) to MCU1 (controller).

So far what I understand about I2C is that it is a command-response protocol. The controler gives commands to the targets, and then the targets respond to this command and send their data to the controller. The targets cannot send their data on their own without receiving the command first.

If the controller wants to receive 32 bytes of data from the target then what command will it send to the target and then how will the target assert that it has received the valid command for data send? I think this is called 'block-mode' data transfer.

My target address is fixed as 0x08.

Comment: If you want to communicate from the MCU2 to MCU1, the MCU2 must be in master mode and the MCU1 in slave mode.
In your case, you must put MCU1 and MCU2 in slave mode. When the MCU1 or MCU2 need to communicate on the bus, it status must be changed to MASTER and then it will ask on the bus.

Comment: Its a little confusing above about the change of mode for MCU2. Why do I need to change the modes? Can I do the data transfer with fixed modes for MCU1 and MCU2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately or unfortunately, it's up to you to come up with a protocol for this scenario as you control both sides.
Like you say, the slave can only respond to transfers initiated by the master. Your master then needs to poll the slave (ask for data on a recurring schedule), unless you have another way for the slave to communicate when data is ready. (The latter is commonly solved with a separate interrupt line.) The master and slave need to both agree on a special response when the slave doesn't yet have data available. The slave also needs to reset its response to this "no data" value after being queried by the master, to avoid sending the same data twice.

The easier way would be to switch the roles of master and slave, so it's the master that initiates sending data to the slave.

If you need to also communicate with other slaves on the same I2C bus, you will however be limited in which device can be the master, unless you use the multi-master mode of I2C.

The particular I2C API calls required depends on what device and HAL you are using. On a physical level, it will be a "I2C read" initiated by the master, where the master reads 32 bytes after sending the slave address.

Comment: The library function that I am using has option to select I2C address as 7-bit or 10-bit. How should i decide about it?

Comment: Doesn't really matter as long as you use the same setting on both sides. As you don't need 10-bit, I suggest 7-bit.

Comment: It means that 7-bit address means that 7-bits for address and additional 3 bits for S, R/W, ACK bits. Similarly 10-bit address means 10-bits for address and additional 3 bits as above AND not as 7+3 bits = 10 bits?

Comment: In the 'Block-mode' data transfer if I set the size of block as 1-byte or 2-bytes then will it be same as 'single Byte-mode' or 'single Word-mode'?

Comment: Yes. I don't think "single word-mode" is a term used. I2C works on a byte level. Your master could query the slave with a single byte to check if data is available, but it will be more complex to get two different transmission lengths to work. I2C can be complex enough to debug as it is.

Comment: If my I2C Master (MCU1) has Linux on it and I use 'i2cset() https://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cset' and 'i2cget() https://linux.die.net/man/8/i2cget' utilities to communicate and get data from the i2C Slave (MCU2) then what will be the meaning of parameter 'data-address' in the above utilities? I can understand that 'chip-address' is my Slave address = 0x08, but what will be the next parameter in my case where the Slave is an MCU and not a sensor chip? Generally in the case of the sensor chips this above parameter is the address of the target register from which the data will be read.

Comment: It is common to use a concept of "registers" on top of the basic I2C, where one byte is used as address among a range of custom-defined value slots (for lack of better word) within the addressed slave. Not all chips use registers and indeed you have no use of this since you only report one 32-byte parameter. To use registers you would need to implement it in the slave. Linux i2cset only works with registers. i2cget might not use registers when not specifying one -- I don't know.